# Multiple stdin Terminal Inputs from an ArrayList Using BufferedWriter

Tags: java

Trying to take an ArrayList and input all its Strings into a command line program, then grab the output. I'm only able to go one time through the loop, before the streams are closed and I cannot use them anymore (java IOException Stream Closed). I have to close the streams, because otherwise I can't get the output from the program for a given input that comes from the ArrayList. Is there any way around this?

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()) );

for(String sequence : editedSequences){
                stdout.write(sequence);
                stdout.close();
                String line = "";
                line = stdin.readLine();
                while ((line = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
                    structure += line;
                }
                stdin.close();
                System.out.println("seq: " + sequence);
                System.out.println("struc: " + structure);
                structure = structure.substring(0, sequence.length());
                System.out.println("struc: " + structure);
                sequenceStructurePair = new String[]{sequence, structure};
                sequenceStructurePairs.add(sequenceStructurePair); 
}
```

Comment: @EJP are you sure about that edit? The outputstream is called stdin because it is the stdin of the other process...

Comment: I was wondering what was even edited here. The writer is stdin, reader is stdout - period. The InputStream technically reads the output of the process, and the outputstream technically reads the input. Anyway, focus more on answering my question than (incorrect) semantics!

Comment: You should be able to revert the edit.

Comment: Done. What's even more strange about that edit is that it clearly would change the whole meaning of the code...

Comment: It didn't make sense to me to be reading from `stdout,` or writing to `stdin.` It still doesn't.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. Stdin is input. Input is written. Stdout is output. Output is read.

Answer (score 0):

Dont close the streams. Instead, flush the input stream after writing to it (`stdin.flush()`).

Comment: This just causes the program to hang. As I said, it NEEDS to be closed. writing and reading during runtime here

Comment: Which program? The one running in Process p? Why does it need to be closed?

Comment: @TomBurns if the program you are calling in Process p only executes when you close its standard input, you will need to restart it if you want to pass it more data, as OutputStreams cannot be reopened (cf. OutputStream.close()'s contract)

Comment: No idea why, actually. It's a quirk; it just hangs if I don't close it.

Comment: @TomBurns So basically, the program in Process p will only write to stdout after stdin has been closed? What is the point of writing more to its stdin afterwards, as it cannot read/write/do anything about it? (It can't read anything from stdin after it has been closed) Either restart the proces for every input, or write all inputs in one go.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just restarting the process. The thing is, though, I know that's unnecessary -- this process is continuous. It will keep taking input and producing output. Writing all inputs in one go is not an option, unless I wanna go the source route (spent 3hrs, biojava sucks, not doing that again).

Answer (score 0):

The fix here was I simply added everything I had outside the for loop to the inside of the for loop. I assume for someone (very) particularly concerned with speed that this would be a potentially problematic approach, but I'm more concerned with this working -- I don't care, for example, if a large file takes 5-10 minutes longer to process as a result of constantly having to discard and make new objects.

I definitely want to hear from more people, though. Again, I can't remove the .close() on the BufferedWriter without causing the program to hang.